# How to update ProgressBar in TableViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my TableViewer I have an OwnerDrawLabelProvider where for a specific column in my table I add a ProgressBar to a TableEditor instance.

My problem is the following:

I'm able to set the selection of the ProgressBar but when trying to update it remains at the same value.

CODE:

```
@Override
public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
if(columnIndex == 4){

            Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
            TableItem item;
            TableItem[] items;
            TableEditor editor;             

            items = table.getItems();
            ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(table, SWT.NONE);
            bar.setMinimum(0);
            bar.setMaximum(100);
            bar.setState(SWT.NORMAL);
            bar.setSelection(0);
            bar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.CENTER,true,true));
            if(mediator.isSent()){
                List<Item> itemsSendToSubmit = mediator.getItemsSendToSubmit();
                if(!itemsSendToSubmit.isEmpty()){
                    for(Iterator<Item> itemIterator = itemsSendToSubmit.iterator(); itemIterator.hasNext(); )
                    {
                        Item itemSubmited = itemIterator.next();                        
                        for(TableItem tableItem: items)
                        {                               if(tableItem.getText(0).contains(itemSubmited.getId())) 
                            {                   
                            bar.setSelection(PluginUtility.getBuildProgress(itemSubmited.getPlan()));
                                editor = new TableEditor(table);
                                editor.grabHorizontal = true;
                                editor.grabVertical = true;

                                editor.setEditor(bar, tableItem, 4);                    

                            }
                        }                   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I read about an issue that setSelection method for ProgressBar has some problems. I created my own ProgressBar by extending the base class and I overrided setSelection method with the fix code but still doesn't work.

In a normal main function, this works.

Can I get some suggestions of what can be the problem or how adding this ProgressBar in a TableViewer influences its behavior ?

**EDIT: If I create a single instance of progressbar when the label provider is created and then pass it to the tableeditor it will update the progressbar for the last element on which I say editor.setEditor(bar, tableItem, 4);
but I need to display a progressbar for each item and update it for each item !**

Comment: Are you updating the same ProgressBar instance? Or you create a new one on each update. If you use the same instance you should update its state just calling setSelection( ... );

Comment: A new instance on each update. In fact it doesn't matter since I always create the editor and set the new instance to it.

Comment: Can you tell how many items the table will have? For a large amount of items I recommend to _draw_ the progress bar in order to save resources.

Comment: I don't know the number of items the table will have, that is dynamic !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the update happens, but the visuals are not updated, depending on how you call this code.

You have to make sure that you're not mobilizing the ui thread when you're doing this update.

In eclipse 3.x this means using

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // ... do any work that updates the screen ...
  }
});
```

Or using injection to get the UISynchronize in 4.x

Basically put the setSelection code in there.

See this article on background processing in eclipse plugins :
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html

Answer (score 0):

When you update the value of ProgressBar, after that you need to redraw/repaint the TableViewer with all of its properties, then it will show the update progressbar. Hope this will solve your problem.